# Is it possible to say "ASAP" instead of "as soon as possible" when we speak?

Tags: formality, colloquialisms, acronyms

Or is it just an abbreviation that should be written just on paper? I heard Al Pacino say "*asap*" on the phone when he was talking with his friend.

What about **pm**? Could we say **p m** instead of prime minister?

Comment: You can say anything you like if you think those you're speaking to will understand you.

Comment: The military has used "ASAP" verbally for decades, and it is spoken in AmE (*and* understood). People also mostly understand STAT, even if not it's origin. We have no PMs here, so I can't help you with that one.

Comment: You can spell out all four letters, or pronounce the last three like the word *sap*.  I've heard it both ways.

Comment: If you actually heard Al Pacino say it, you have just answered your own question. There is no such thing as "should be written just on paper". If it's written, it can be read; if it can be read, it can be read aloud.

Answer (score 3):

ASAP is an informal term and hence more appropriate for spoken rather than written English.

ASAP even when written, may be used in informal mails or while texting. It is not recommended usage in formal communication, as of now.

PM is fairly well accepted and regularly used in National dailies and for that matter all types of communication. A prior reference to the full form is recommended before reverting to the abbreviated version.

Whatever is acceptable in written English is, by large, acceptable in spoken English. Even though it may sound a little formal at times, there are very few chances of going wrong. The reverse however does not hold true.